# Total disk space used for one directory including it's sub-directories

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

On a Linux environment.  How can I find out the total space a folder is taking.  It would like this total to include ALL sub-directories in the total.  I don't want a dump of the size of each subdirectory. Just the total size a directory is taking up with the size of all it's subdirectories included in the c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> du -sh /path/to/directory

The output will return sumarize and human readeable directory size.

or in MB

> du --max-depth=0 --one-file-system -m /path/to/directory

Also, you can create an alias if you will going to execute this command often.
If you want to know more about du command, execute: man du

Answer (score 2):

```
du -sh /path/to/directory
```

Should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> du --max-depth=0 --one-file-system -m

Gives the size of the current directory in MB, not running past mount-points.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$ du -skh <directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside the directory, `du -skh .` works well. Otherwise, `du -skh /path/to/directory` is good.

The flags on that command mean "-s summary, -k kilobyte listing, -h human-readable suffixes". The "-k" is probably redundant, but a force of habit.